# 3 midpoints on one line

Tags: geometry

Prove that the three midpoints: K, of the segment AB, L, of the segment GD, and M, of the segment HI are on a straight line.

[image]

I was told the Menelaus proved this over 2000 years ago but could not find such proof, so any proof will be appreciated.

Comment: What else do you know about the figure? The problem does not seem properly determined right now.

Comment: Given the rectangle HGID, HD and GI are extended to create B and HG and DI are extended to create A. Is this clarifies it?

Comment: You mean quadrilateral HGID, I suppose?

Comment: You are right:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof using barycentric coordinates . . .

Choosing coordinates with respect to the triangle $\Delta ABH$,  let

\begin{align*}
A &= (1,0,0)\\[4pt]
B &= (0,1,0)\\[4pt]
H &= (0,0,1)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Then
\begin{align*}
D &= H + d(B-H) = (0,d,1-d)\\[4pt]
G &= H + g(A-H) = (g,0,1-g)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

for some real numbers $d,g$ with $0 < d,g < 1$.

The point $I$ is on line segments $BG$ and $AD$, hence the barycentric coordinates of $I$ can be expressed in two ways:

\begin{align*}
I &= D + p(A-D) = \bigl(p,\,(1-p)d,\,(1-p)(1-d)\bigr)\\[4pt]
I &= G + q(B-G) = \bigl((1-q)g,\,q,\,(1-q)(1-g)\bigr)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

for some real numbers $p,q$ with $0 < p,q < 1$.

But since barycentric coordinates are unique, we get the system of equations

\begin{align*}
p&= (1-q)g\\[4pt]
(1-p)d &= q\\[4pt]
(1-p)(1-d) &= (1-q)(1-g)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

where the third equation is dependent on the first two, so isn't needed.

Solving the system for $p,q$ yields

\begin{align*}
p &= \frac{g(1-d)}{1-dg}\\[4pt]
q &= \frac{d(1-g)}{1-dg}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Using the above values of $p,q$, the point $I$ can be re-expressed as

$$I = \left({\small{\frac{1}{1-dg}}}\right)\bigl(g(1-d),d(1-g),(1-d)(1-g)\bigr)$$

Computing the points $K,L,M$, we get

\begin{align*}
&K  = {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(A+B) = {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(1,1,0)\\[6pt]
&L  = {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(G+D) = {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(g,d,2-d-g)\\[6pt]
&M  = {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(I+H) = {\small{\frac{1}{2(1-dg)}}}\bigl(g(1-d),d(1-g),2-d-g\bigr)\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

Then, letting $t=dg$, we get

\begin{align*}
tK + (1-t)M &= (dg)\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(1,1,0)\right)
+(1-dg)\left({\small{\frac{1}{2(1-dg)}}}\bigl(g(1-d),d(1-g),2-d-g\bigr)\right)
\\[6pt]
&= {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(dg,dg,0)
+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigl(g(1-d),d(1-g),2-d-g\bigr)
\\[6pt]
&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(g,d,2-d-g)\\[6pt]
&=L\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

Thus, $L$ is a convex combination of $K$ and $M$.

It follows that $K,L,M$ are concurrent, as was to be shown.

Comment: Could you assume that ABH equilateral? Does barycentric allow for projection?